# Can the $in operator return null for unmatched documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a requirement to return the same length of the array provided to mongo.

`usernames = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']`

Now lets say `user3` doesn't exist, is there a way to return null when mongo doesn't find the document ?

If i'm using the `$in` operator i only get the matched documents ex.

`User.find({ username: { $in: usernames }})`

`result = [user1Document, user2Document]`

I can loop over the array and query the database for every username but it's not efficient.

```
const userPromises = usernames.map(username => User.findOne({ username }));
return Promise.all(userPromises);
```

Comment: You should use iteration to return `null` for the non-existing elements as you did. Aggregation trick might help here but it is even more costly then the looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with initial filtering using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) and then to map all the values from input array into final result you have to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) them [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html)-ing `$$ROOT` (enitre document), then you can just merge input `usernames` with `docs` using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operators:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { username: { $in: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            results: {
                $map: {
                    input: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
                    as: 'username',
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: { 
                                filtered: { 
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$docs",
                                        as: "doc",
                                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$doc.username", "$$username" ] } 
                                    }
                                } 
                            },
                            in: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [ "$$filtered", 0 ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e7rva5Y11-q)

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: How can i do the same operation with ObjectIds ? when i try to change username to _id i'm getting `'_id' starts with an invalid character for a user variable name`

Comment: @AsafAviv yes you can but I need to see your code to see why you're getting that error, please use mongo playground for that

Comment: @AsafAviv `_id` is a special string in MongoDB, try this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/bkv9RItfW5U

Comment: I don't want to match username this time i have a list of document ids to match but return null for unmatched documents

Comment: Just change `username` to `_id` like here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/biN_a2Z1RJN

Comment: Nice, Thank you for your time @mickl i appreciate it!